# keycloak / nginx. Can't access to admin page (Invalid parameter: redirect_uri )

Tags: nginx, keycloak

**edit:**
***Using  PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING=true in my docker env file, like Jan suggested solved my issue.***

I tried keycloak on local host and it successfully worked.
I'm now trying to build one with a valid https domain and I can't access  the login page. I get a redirect_uri error. 
What I am missing?

When I go on the home page it works. But accessing the admin page, I get a redirection.

```
https://keycloak.myDomain.com/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/auth?client_id=security-admin-console&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fkeycloak.myDomain.com%2Fauth%2Fadmin%2Fmaster%2Fconsole%2F&state=ef6b5ac7-f2f4-49c1-81de-6c0d4cf18e5f&response_mode=fragment&response_type=code&scope=openid&nonce=a46f44b8-9428-4019-8d18-e8e58e896ef2
```

I'm using a simple docker image with no configuration.

```
services:
  postgres:
      image: postgres:9.4
      volumes:
        - ./init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
        - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  keycloak:
      image: jboss/keycloak
      env_file:
       - docker-variables.env
      ports:
        - 9000:8080
      depends_on:
        - postgres
```

And I'm using Nginx with this conf:

```
server {
server_name  keycloak.myDomain.com;
resolver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 valid=300s;
resolver_timeout 5s;

location / {
      proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:9000;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

      # enable this if and only if you use HTTPS
      proxy_set_header            X-Forwarded-Proto https;
      proxy_set_header            Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header            X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header            X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }


    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/myDomain.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/myDomain.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you use PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING=true for Keycloak container?

Comment: Jan... What can i say... I love you! I just added this PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING=true in my docker environ file, and it worked like a charm! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting the redirect_uri error when trying to log into the admin console, keep in mind there are two environment  variables that have to be set for Keycloak to work behind a reverse proxy. If the URL of the admin console is https://your.fqdn/auth  then your must set:

```
KEYCLOAK_FRONTEND_URL = https://your.fqdn/auth
```

and

```
PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING = true
```